# Function that executes after insert

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, triggers, insertafter

I want to execute a function after an insert operation that is accessing the newly inserted data by calling another function. That is why I cannot use an after-insert trigger. Since, the inner function is not accessing the data with ":new".
Is there a way to first do the insert in dependent of the trigger and then execute a function?

```
trigger insert_to_A after insert on tableX for each row
begin

    insert into tableA values (function1(:new.field1));

end;


create or replace function function1(abc number) return number as
begin

select nvl(field1,-1)
into nMax1
from tableX
where field1= abc;

end;
```

So, the function1 is trying to access the tableX in its body and I believe that is the problem. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. It is not clear what your exact requirement is. Do you want to get the inserted rows to process it differently? If yes, you could use `RETURNING INTO` clause. Have a look at an example here http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/07/returning-the-sequence-number-of-identity-column-after-insert/

Comment: I don't think that is relevant to what I tried to explain in any way. I wanna execute a function after an insert operation. But I want it in a way that the insert operation and the trigger are not executed in an atomic way. i want first the insert operation to go through so that i can run a function on the new state of the table (with the new rows inserted) without using the ":new" keyword. I hope that makes it a bit more clear

Comment: Perhaps an example would be better. If you could **edit your question and add a test case**. I am still confused the flow of your process. Is a trigger already on the table doing something? What are the functions going to do?

Comment: Why do you want to not use :new? Also, can't you knock up a simple test case that demonstrates what it is you're trying to do? (eg. create table and insert statements, along with the results that you're after). That way, we stand a much better chance of a) working out what you're after and b) helping you to achieve it. Currently it's all a bit "I've got this thing, and I want to do this other thing, and I want it to end up like this {waves hands}"; almost impossible to decipher, given we're not sat with you and can't see your screen over your shoulder.

Comment: So you want to execute `function1` only after the insert is completed on `tableX`?

Comment: is this function trying to pick the next number to update a column that's a sequence? If so, is that not something that you could use an actual sequence to populate?

Comment: You want if field1's value isn't existing, replace to"-1". Don't you? and Did You get error "ORA-04091: table name is mutating"? if so which version do you use? Finally, you need to declare and return "nMax1" in your function.

Comment: I got sqlsyntaxerrorexception. I am not trying to pick the next number. And yes I want to execute function1 only after the insert is completed on tableX so that the select statement takes the new row into consideration.

Comment: Give some sample data and what you want to happen to it after an insert. Thus far this whole thing doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get error like "ORA-04091: table name is mutating"?

The error will occur when you select, insert or update in the same table that trigger fired.

You can avoid this error by [COMPOUND TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CHDFEBFJ)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_to_A 
FOR insert on tableX 
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    -- Put your function or statement
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

  BEFORE each ROW IS
  BEGIN
    -- Put your statement
  END BEFORE each ROW;
END insert_to_A;
```

> Note: You can not use ":NEW" in "AFTER STATEMENT" body is limitation.

Statements under "AFTER STATEMENT", you can select, update, and insert in tableX. It will do 1 time for 1 statement.

Statements under "BEFORE each ROW", you can't select, update, and insert in tableX. It will do 1 time for each affected row.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an after statement trigger that will fire only once after the insert. Problem is how to identify the rows that need further processing (theoretically this can be more than one record).

Probably the simplest solution is to add a column to the table that will indicate if the record needs further processing.

Otherwise you can gather the PK values of the inserted rows in a collection in a package and use that collection in the after statement trigger. You will need: a package with a collection, a row level trigger to place PK value in collection, an after statement trigger that uses the collection.

Comment: I don't need to identify specific rows at all. I just need to do an operation on all the rows of the table (including the newly inserted rows). How do I create an after statement trigger that fire only once after the insert?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to perform an action on the entire table after an insert? Anyway, the documentation is usually a good start.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm